# Synonym for discovery?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm working on a backend product and the term ["eDiscovery"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_discovery) is overused in my industry. What's another appropriate word that has enough resonance to be marketable?
*Discovery* in this context does not seem to be appropriate.

Comment: Finding or Findings

Comment: I'm not familiar with the meaning of "eDiscovery". If you could provide a little background, that would help a lot to discover a marketable synonym.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too broad, it's opinion-based, and it's unclear what you're asking. We are being asked to provide a marketable word for a product we know very little about. _Whizbang_ and _DooHickey_ would be as viable as any other candidates, with the slim amount of background information and market research provided.

Comment: I find it rather bold to seek a marketably resonant word (in short, a copy!) at a linguist forum. You're talking about this "discovery":  "_Law._ The compulsory disclosure of pertinent facts or documents to the opposing party in a civil action, usually before a trial begins." In having _that_ process as a referent, the word 'discovery' is not so much a concept-identifier, a lexicon entry, a name — as a firm, a happy label, a nickname. And a euphemism at that. Synonyms for catchphrases?! The Marketing Department is on another extension.

Comment: I see no harm in this question. It is reasonable to seek an alternative label. As Talia Ford says 'discovery' is not really an apt word in this context - and OP's quest for an alternative is justified.

Comment: I see it as unjustified, because his title says "synonym for discovery", and here, all he wanted was that we did his copy. That's not a language question, that's a marketing question. I may be wrong, but your argument hasn't swayed me to turnabout on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An appropriate synonym that immediately springs to mind is ***disclosure.***

You might also consider ***reveal.***

Answer (score 0):

**Eureka**—the most appropriate synonym for discovery that I can think of.